Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression. JS
I encountered a problem where JsHint throws the following error:
"Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."
on line:
const OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
Here's the surrounding code:
    selBranch.parentId = parentId;
    selBranch.expanded = 'false';
    
    const OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
    if (fireDisplay != null) {
        for (var n in fireDisplay) {
            if( fireDisplay.hasOwnProperty(n) && !OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L.includes(n)){
                selBranch[n] = fireDisplay[n];
            }   
        }
    }

I came back to JS after a long break and this has me stumped.
Mind you, it seems to be working fine, it's just that JsHint has some issue with the line and it's probably something trivial.
I asked about setting expr=true in custom options but 'No' is all I got.
Is there another way of doing this that won't trigger during validation?

There's nothing wrong with that line of code. It's just your linter doesn't like it. Make sure you're using the latest version

What is the configuration you have for JSHint? This should work with esversion: 6. But also, you shouldn't be getting that error, either. What version of JSHint do you use? It seems like it doesn't support ES6 or something.

I think JSHint sees that OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L is only referenced inside the if-block, so it wants it to be declared in that scope.
Either move it into the if-block, or disable the rule around the assignment:
/* jshint -W030 */
const OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
/* jshint +W030 */

Rule W030 is an alias for expr:true:
/* jshint expr:true */
const OBJECT_PROTOTYPE_L = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Object.prototype);
/* jshint expr:false */

Note: The warning message "Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression." is identified as W030.
